# Why is the `NAME` attribute considered unsafe?

Tags: php, attributes, html-parsing, pear, html-sanitizing

I'm passing user-generated HTML into a database and I'm trying to make sure that no malicious code is passed through. One of the steps I'm taking is to run passed code through pear's [HTML_Safe](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Safe) class to remove vulnerable markup. However, one thing I've noticed is that the `name` attribute of submitted elements gets removed. Sure enough, when you look at the source code, `name` is one of the few attributes that's blacklisted by default:

[http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Safe/docs/latest/HTML_Safe/HTML_Safe.html#var$attributes](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Safe/docs/latest/HTML_Safe/HTML_Safe.html#var%24attributes)

What's the danger in allowing users to pass values for `name`? How can values for `name` be used to nefarious ends? Any thoughts? If not, I'm tempted to modify the blacklist.

Comment: Probably because forms in general are not really the kind of things people would need to post.

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where allowing users to build form-contents through direct DOM manipulation could come in handy. The question is whether there is anything to worry about other than the "it could end up getting submitted if a form element ends up with the code inside it")... which is easy enough to protect against by simply not `echo`ing the posted code inside a form element (the `form` tag is already blacklisted, as is all js, so you'd have to be very sloppy to end up with submitted `inputs` ending up being submitted)

Comment: [This article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/) suggests that `name` and `id` can sometimes mean the same thing in certain browsers, so that could be considered dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML form elements, the `name` attribute is used as an identifier. Therefore, if you allow `name` then someone may be able to override *your* HTML `name` attributes (that you may have used) with one of their own. The first matching `name` found is often the one used by either Javascript or server side processing.

This would then allow someone to exploit any possible Javascript or server side form processing you may be using that references the first matching `name` attribute found.

It is not just form elements that can use `name`, but they would be the least safe ones.

Another override issue is if you are using Javascripts `getElementsByName` in any of your functions (as pointed out below), you could end up with a function that does not do what you expect.

Edit: Some corrections and a note about `getElementsByName` issue (as pointed out below).

Comment: That's not correct. `id` is unique, but `name` can be used as many times as you'd like on forms and inputs (hence why the js functions to get elements by name - `getElementsByName` always returns an array rather than a single element: because you can have multiple elements with the same `name`. And I understand that there is sometimes JS logic that can be affected by new names, but these days `class` is a more common selector... or even just tag names. I don't see `name` as being any more dangerous than most other attributes in that respect.

Comment: However, the basic point - that if included in a form with elements that share the same name it could get passed back to a server side script - is well-taken. In that respect it does pose more of a threat. The JS worry seems pretty insignificant (given how rarely `name` is used as a selector) but I buy the explanation that it poses a greater danger if it makes its way into a form. You should clarify your answer: `name` is not a unique identifier: not even within a single form. However, the `name` defines the keys of the `_POST` array, which are unique, and might pick up the inserted input.